# Java library to create a PDF with address positioned to be visible through a C5 envelope

Tags: library, java, pdf

I'm working with an automatic mailing service, which accepts a PDF document, prints it, puts it in a post envelope and drops it in the postal service mail box for shipping.

My challenge is that this service expects the destination address to be **perfectly positioned** so that it is visible from the [window of a C5 envelope](https://shop.post.ch/medias/sys_master/images/images/h3f/h83/8915925565470/product-759131-mainpicture-Default-WorkingFormat-380Wx380H.jpg).

At the moment, to generate PDFs I use [openhtmltopdf](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf), which has many advantages, but precise positioning via HTML is very very hard to achieve.

Moreover addresses vary a lot between one another.

Do you have a solution to recommend that is able to meet this precise positioning constraint?

Comment: Using Apache PdfBox you can specify the exact position by pixel. The following example is for v1.8 but still works for 2.x: https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/documentcreation.html